# How can I take care of hate content while avoiding backlash for censoring anything I disagree with?

Tags: problem-users, spam, backlash, deletion, offensive-content

On any community site, there will be people who just want to you it as a platform to attack a person, group, or idea. How do I deal with it? Obviously, I could remove it. But often times that doesn't work very well. People who didn't know what it was that was removed just see a message along the lines of "Removed because it was offensive". Often times people think (sometimes rightfully so) that I am just censoring content I disagree with. How do I take care of the content and avoid backlash and problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am going to wind up doing it putting a feature where it says something like "This has been removed as being hate content and is therefore automatically hidden. If you wish to see it, click here, although be aware that it is offensive." The click here gives a link to the bad post. This way, if anyone wants to see the content, they can. Therefore, they are less likely to say that I am censoring content I disagree with. After all, it is hate content. Most people would agree with removing it, but most people also believe everyone is out to censor information as well.